# Application unable to start Service

Tags: java, c++, windows, windows-services

I have a restAPI made in java which will run on Client machines as a Service using [WINSW](https://github.com/kohsuke/winsw).  I am using [Advanced Installer](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/) to generate installer for this. I tested it on 7 PCs (Windows 10). 5/7 are success. On the other 2 it prompts that you don't have enough privileges to start the service. I checked group Policy "Log on as a Service",

- added Admin in it, restart PC, try to install again, no result.
- emptied the ploicy, restart PC, try to install again, no result.
- Added "All application Packages", restart PC, try to install again, no result.

What am i doing wrong here? Or rather what is the setting which allowed the installer to install on 5 PCs but not on the other 2.

Edit:
Advanced Installer will run the exe under "Local System" account if no credentials are given while creating the installer for your Application.

Comment: I'm confusing about java tag

Comment: This module is of Spring-Boot, using socket programming, which will be accessed by The MAIN APP. The jar that this module generates is run as Windows Service using WINSW.

Comment: Then you have explain it well with all details

Comment: Please add your WinSW configuration file.